# Combining 97 items like jpg, png and mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 3 mp4 videos with audio and 92 jpg images and 1 png image. I need merge all of them, since images dont have audio i have added dummy audio at the end.

```
-f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100
```

I checked all mp4 video have 30 fps. But im getting error when i run this command in terminal. I have added error end of this question.

> ffmpeg -i vlog.mp4 -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> 176289846_105097328309081_601023439308451104_n.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i
> 2048x2730--elleuk-com-gallery-2543-k-launches-the-estee-edit-at-selfridges-london-rex-gallery-jpg.jpg
> -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i 240509456_951357192092578_7024031524462711198_n.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i 269773026_139944861743460_5973031789377429736_n.jpg -loop
> 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> 272185356_5184945991539492_8655458649809306173_n.jpg -loop 1
> -framerate 30 -t 10 -i 272982846_982963685973335_4505762263706805155_n.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i 284894134_779193733247375_8179012576894655236_n.jpg -loop
> 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> 292010277_105616508829281_6546460775317951397_n.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i 299579923_366974645463442_3067763790958680676_n.jpg -loop
> 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> 308586860_1460806071064928_724646131074541655_n.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i 316251042_1182932825658575_1973331576384811644_n.jpg -loop
> 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> 317375204_825333288586225_3494327956540386564_n.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i 320657986_171627788829176_6704693822753482970_n.jpg -i
> 336023902_1388216378646434_1274549774807386832_n1.mp4 -loop 1
> -framerate 30 -t 10 -i 336023902_1388216378646434_1274549774807386832_n.jpg -loop 1
> -framerate 30 -t 10 -i 337139845_175124041999226_2450227144918414731_n.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i 341010813_1260501997880528_5775042343016088518_n.jpg -loop
> 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> 350350134_628274322245654_7834055219271640131_n.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i bguk-1806442-001-1-1575885182.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t
> 10 -i gallery-1501231161-rexfeatures-8975296f.jpg -loop 1 -framerate
> 30 -t 10 -i gallery-1501490122-gettyimages-824543634.jpg -loop 1
> -framerate 30 -t 10 -i gallery-1501662360-rexfeatures-8979657s.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i gallery-1519118258-gettyimages-920660202.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t
> 10 -i gettyimages-1007594756-1-1533302417.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t
> 10 -i gettyimages-1041395230-1-1545137745.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t
> 10 -i gettyimages-1041507006.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1046789262.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1056952122.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-10597661501.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1059766150.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1061995120.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1068006128.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1071199786-1-1545137825.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1166095264.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1166462980.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1166619485.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1172717451.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1173046637.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1193584885.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1204872171.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1206702698.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1231869163.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1233125094.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1233143812.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1238147989.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1239252757.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1308337144.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1339403524.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1395051825.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1395099206.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1486931966-1-64506b1876fe3.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10
> -i gettyimages-1497108210-6486cde03c9cb.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i gettyimages-1661158508.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1663746244.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1667813271.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1667909592.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1668160883.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-1673863517.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-626934148.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-631291776.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-632556354.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-639891306.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-670606036.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-685410728.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-686201670.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-686442088.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-686480630.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-686749012.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-690994782.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-691692354.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-692007384.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-692204670.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-805671172.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-806281110.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-809176540.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-810594198.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-902346518.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-911129522.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-911331944.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-916007400.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-916331340.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-927557366-1523295081.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-942427832-1523295081.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-956246212-1532081998.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-956938402-1532081997.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-957678822-1532082000.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-957710836-1532081997.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-967568846-1532081998.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-969598422-1532081998.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> gettyimages-973460626-1532081998.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> k-style-file-1642411215.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> k-style-file-643d14ad02791.png -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> k-stylefile-july2016-2.jpg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i
> k-wears-bottega-veneta-2-1669215583.jpg -i
> app_video_308468950_1515994365517349_3800958547012720966_n.mp4 -f
> lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100
> -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][96:a][2:v][96:a][3:v][96:a][4:v][96:a][5:v][96:a][6:v][96:a][7:v][96:a][8:v][96:a][9:v][96:a][10:v][96:a][11:v][96:a][12:v][96:a][13:v][96:a][14:v][14:a][15:v][96:a][16:v][96:a][17:v][96:a][18:v][96:a][19:v][96:a][20:v][96:a][21:v][96:a][22:v][96:a][23:v][96:a][24:v][96:a][25:v][96:a][26:v][96:a][27:v][96:a][28:v][96:a][29:v][96:a][30:v][96:a][31:v][96:a][32:v][96:a][33:v][96:a][34:v][96:a][35:v][96:a][36:v][96:a][37:v][96:a][38:v][96:a][39:v][96:a][40:v][96:a][41:v][96:a][42:v][96:a][43:v][96:a][44:v][96:a][45:v][96:a][46:v][96:a][47:v][96:a][48:v][96:a][49:v][96:a][50:v][96:a][51:v][96:a][52:v][96:a][53:v][96:a][54:v][96:a][55:v][96:a][56:v][96:a][57:v][96:a][58:v][96:a][59:v][96:a][60:v][96:a][61:v][96:a][62:v][96:a][63:v][96:a][64:v][96:a][65:v][96:a][66:v][96:a][67:v][96:a][68:v][96:a][69:v][96:a][70:v][96:a][71:v][96:a][72:v][96:a][73:v][96:a][74:v][96:a][75:v][96:a][76:v][96:a][77:v][96:a][78:v][96:a][79:v][96:a][80:v][96:a][81:v][96:a][82:v][96:a][83:v][96:a][84:v][96:a][85:v][96:a][86:v][96:a][87:v][96:a][88:v][96:a][89:v][96:a][90:v][96:a][91:v][96:a][92:v][96:a][93:v][96:a][94:v][96:a][95:v][95:a]concat=n=96:v=3:a=3"
> out.mp4

**Error:**

> Input #95, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
> 'app_video_308468950_1515994365517349_3800958547012720966_n.mp4':
> Metadata:
> major_brand     : isom
> minor_version   : 512
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41   Duration: 00:00:07.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1707 kb/s
> Stream #95:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 576x720, 1614 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60
> tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
> Stream #95:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : SoundHandler Input #96, lavfi, from 'anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100':   Duration: N/A,
> start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
> Stream #96:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description
> [0:v][0:a][1:v][96:a][2:v][96:a][3:v][96:a][4:v][96:a][5:v][96:a][6:v][96:a][7:v][96:a][8:v][96:a][9:v][96:a][10:v][96:a][11:v][96:a][12:v][96:a][13:v][96:a][14:v][14:a][15:v][96:a][16:v][96:a][17:v][96:a][18:v][96:a][19:v][96:a][20:v][96:a][21:v][96:a][22:v][96:a][23:v][96:a][24:v][96:a][25:v][96:a][26:v][96:a][27:v][96:a][28:v][96:a][29:v][96:a][30:v][96:a][31:v][96:a][32:v][96:a][33:v][96:a][34:v][96:a][35:v][96:a][36:v][96:a][37:v][96:a][38:v][96:a][39:v][96:a][40:v][96:a][41:v][96:a][42:v][96:a][43:v][96:a][44:v][96:a][45:v][96:a][46:v][96:a][47:v][96:a][48:v][96:a][49:v][96:a][50:v][96:a][51:v][96:a][52:v][96:a][53:v][96:a][54:v][96:a][55:v][96:a][56:v][96:a][57:v][96:a][58:v][96:a][59:v][96:a][60:v][96:a][61:v][96:a][62:v][96:a][63:v][96:a][64:v][96:a][65:v][96:a][66:v][96:a][67:v][96:a][68:v][96:a][69:v][96:a][70:v][96:a][71:v][96:a][72:v][96:a][73:v][96:a][74:v][96:a][75:v][96:a][76:v][96:a][77:v][96:a][78:v][96:a][79:v][96:a][80:v][96:a][81:v][96:a][82:v][96:a][83:v][96:a][84:v][96:a][85:v][96:a][86:v][96:a][87:v][96:a][88:v][96:a][89:v][96:a][90:v][96:a][91:v][96:a][92:v][96:a][93:v][96:a][94:v][96:a][95:v][95:a]concat=n=96:v=3:a=3
> matches no streams.

Comment: maybe, error in `[95:a]`, and, maybe, next error will be at this point `:v=3:a=3`